# React variables change in jsx

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Good afternoon!

I have been playing around after following a tutorial and have come across a problem I cant seem to understand.

Whenever I pass on variables through a `this.props.updateSurveyText(this.props.index, newText)` they change back to the old variables when they get into `updateSurveyText={this.updateSurvey.bind(i, newText[0], newText[1])}`

Logging shows the right variables in the first function but when I log them in the second function they are unchanged.

Help is greatly appreciated!

Survey:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

export default class Survey extends React.Component{
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      editing : false,
      title : "",
      desc : "",
    };
    this.edit = this.edit.bind(this);
    this.save = this.save.bind(this);
    this.remove = this.remove.bind(this);
  }

  edit() {
    this.setState({editing: true});
  }

  remove() {
    console.log('delete');
    this.props.deleteFromBoard(this.props.index)
  }

  save() {
    var title = this.refs.newTitle.value;
    var desc = this.refs.newDesc.value;
    var newText = [title, desc];
    console.log(newText[0]);
    this.props.updateSurveyText(this.props.index, newText);
    this.setState({editing: false});
  }

  renderNormal(){
    return(
      <div className="surveyContainer">
        <div className="surveyTitle">{this.props.children[0]}</div>
        <div className="surveyDesc">{this.props.children[1]}</div>
        <button onClick={this.edit} className="button-primary">Edit</button>
        <button onClick={this.remove} className="button-primary">Remove</button>
      </div>
    );
  }

  renderForm(){
    return(
      <div className="surveyContainer">
        <textarea ref="newTitle" defaultValue={this.props.children[0]}></textarea>
        <textarea ref="newDesc" defaultValue={this.props.children[1]}></textarea>
        <button onClick={this.save} className="button-primary">Save</button>
      </div>
    );
  }

  render(){
      if(this.state.editing){
        return this.renderForm();
      }else{
        return this.renderNormal();
      }
  }
}
```

Board:

```
import Survey from './Survey.jsx';
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

export default class Board extends React.Component{
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        surveys: [

        ],
    };
    this.updateSurvey = this.updateSurvey.bind(this);
    this.removeSurvey = this.removeSurvey.bind(this);
    this.eachSurvey = this.eachSurvey.bind(this);
    this.addSurvey = this.addSurvey.bind(this);
  }

  addSurvey(title, desc){
    var arr = this.state.surveys;
    arr.push([title, desc]);
    this.setState({surveys: arr})
  }

  removeSurvey(i){
    var arr = this.state.surveys;
    arr.splice(i, 1);
    this.setState({surveys: arr})
  }

  updateSurvey(newTitle, newDesc, i){
    console.log(newTitle);console.log(newDesc);
    var arra = this.state.surveys;
    arra[i] = [newTitle, newDesc];
    this.setState({surveys: arra});

  }

  eachSurvey(newText, i){
    return(
      <Survey key={i} index={i} updateSurveyText={this.updateSurvey.bind(i, newText[0], newText[1])} deleteFromBoard={this.removeSurvey.bind(i)}>
        {newText[0]}
        {newText[1]}

      </Survey>);
  }

  render(){
    return(
      <div>
        <button onClick={this.addSurvey.bind(null, "Titel", "Desc")}>Add new</button>
        <div className="board">
          {this.state.surveys.map(this.eachSurvey)}
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `updateSurvey` function accepts three arguments.

`updateSurvey(newTitle, newDesc, i)`

When you call `.bind` on a function, you are providing "Arguments to prepend to arguments provided to the bound function when invoking the target function." [Function.prototype.bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind)

which means that when you call

`updateSurveyText={this.updateSurvey.bind(i, newText[0], newText[1])}`

the function passed down as `updateSurveyText` has two arguments permanently prepended to its arguments list whenever it is called. Whatever the value of `newText[0]` and `newText[1]` were at the time that `.bind` was called will be used as the first and second arguments whenever `updateSurveyText` is called.

Here's a example:

```js
function add(first, second) {
  console.log('add called with args: ', first, second);
  console.log('all arguments: ', [].slice.call(arguments));
  return first + second;
}

document.write('add(1, 1) = ' + add(1, 1));
document.write('<br>');

var boundAdd = add.bind(null, 1, 1);

// despite passing new arguments, 2 and 2, the 
// bound function has 1 and 1 bound to it and will not
// use 2 and 2 as the first and second arg.
// 1 and 1 are prepended to the arguments list.
document.write('boundAdd(2, 2) = ' + boundAdd(2, 2));
```

Comment: Thanks for clearing that up, that explains some odd behaviour aswell due to binding. However am not quite sure as how to update a state without binding or how to use binding differently. Could you give a hint as how to fix the issue?

Comment: Don't bind any variables to `updateSurvey` when you pass it to `updateSurveyText`. Your Survey component already has the index in props and the text values are grabbed from your refs. Just pass down `updateSurveyText={this.updateSurvey}` and call it in your `save` function with the correct arguments `this.props.updateSurveyText(newTitle, newDesc, this.props.index);` You don't need to wrap the text pieces in an array. Make sure you pass the `this.props.index` as the third argument. Your example has the arguments out of order.

Comment: Thanks a lot that makes sense! However as you see in my updateSurvey function I call the state like so: var arra = this.state.surveys; this results in a type error: this.state is undefined. Should I pass the state aswell into the function?

Comment: You will still need this line `this.updateSurvey = this.updateSurvey.bind(this);` in your Board component constructor. Is that line still present?

Comment: Sorry! I thought I had to comment that out as well. After uncommenting it everything works now. I really need to take some time to think about what is actually happening with all those binds. Thanks for making me aware of that!